# Using swift 2 to scan an image for the color of its pixels

Tags: swift, macos

I need to figure out how to scan an image for the color of its pixels for a Mac application. My desired end result is to group certain colors and filter them individually. Any and all tips or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This link may help.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25146557/how-do-i-get-the-color-of-a-pixel-in-a-uiimage-with-swift

Comment: Two interesting techniques in this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31026763/count-colors-in-image-nscountedset-and-coloratx-are-very-slow